# Performance evaluation of a model: MAPE in R

Tags: modeling, predictive-models

I'm trying to compare two models. I have got the root mean square error (RMSE) but it's not satisfying. This is why I'm trying to work out the mean absolute percent error (MAPE).

Is there any package in R where I can compute the mean absolute percent error?

Answer (score 15):

You could always code it yourself:

```
mape <- function(y, yhat)
mean(abs((y - yhat)/y))
```

Answer (score 2):

For MAPE, use the following function:

`mape <- function(actual,pred){
           mape <- mean(abs((actual - pred)/actual))*100
           return (mape)
         }`

For the formula, you can refer to the following link:

http://www.forecastpro.com/Trends/forecasting101August2011.html

Comment: -1 this does not add anything to the already existing answer: the only difference is names of the parameters and multiplying by 100...

Comment: @Tim Multiplying by 100 is important for calculating MAPE and that was missing in the earlier answer. I currently do not have the privilege to comment on posts, therefore had to add another answer.

Comment: Actually it does not change anything in the results, it is just about displaying the results in 100s...